# Permanently change cloud function region

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I know you can change the region of a function using the below method. Just wondering if there is a way to permanently set this to all functions so I dont have to do this to each function.

````
exports.myStorageFunction = functions
    .region('europe-west1')
    .storage
    .object()
    .onFinalize((object) => {
      // ...
    }); ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the chaining builder pattern, you can do this:

```
const euFunctions = functions.region('europe-west1');

exports.myFunction = euFunctions.storage.object().onFinalize(...);
```

and it will do what you expect!

Answer (score 0):

One could improve it a little bit by defining an array and use that for all functions. But otherwise than that, there is no other way to my knowledge.

```js
const regionArr = ["europe-west3"];

exports.myFunction = functions.region(...regionArr).https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  ...
});
```